# Como fazer download de arquivos usando puppeteer com headless: true

Tags: javascript, download, chromium, pupeteer

Tenho um sistema que busca em sites de download, alguns arquivos zip,
o download está funcionando perfeito quando uso o modo:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: False})
const page = await browser.newPage()
```

Porém quando coloco como true, e fica "Escondido" não faz nada quando clica em download, testei em vários sistemas e nenhum faz esse download.

Pesquisei no stackoverflow em inglês, achei algumas pessoas falando pra setar o comando a seguir, porém não funciona.

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: 'c:\\XML'});
```

ainda não achei nenhum outro tipo de respostas sobre esse assunto, e pelo que pesquisei, essa é uma dúvida perguntada em fóruns desde 2017, imagino que agora já haja uma solução.

Comment: Opa Luan, existe algum motivo pelo qual você precisa usar o headless igual a true?

Comment: Sim, a ideia é que o processo fique escondido.

Comment: Existe uma integração da dados, e integração com APIs de outras empresas.
O problema é com as grandes empresas que não podem fazer essa parceria, e nos enviar dados por API.
Sendo assim, precisamos logar nas plataformas web e exportar os dados diariamente, usando o próprio login do cliente.
Nesses casos, instalamos uma aplicação local que vai até o sistema, extrai as notas e coloca na nuvem
Não é interessante pro cliente ver o browser mexendo sozinho, mas a ideia é apenas facilitar a vida dos clientes para que não precisem extrair esses dados

Comment: Entendi, pupeteer é algo q me interesso muito, vou estudar alguma forma de fazer isso.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, não sei se lembra mas quem indicou a ferramente foi você em outra pergunta, tu já me ajudou muito :)

Comment: Lembro sim, por isso até estou interessado em ajudar mais kkkk